# Android Volley sometime didnt invoked on onCreate

Tags: android, performance, android-volley

I came up with the problem that sometime Volley didnt run on onCreate.

Does anybody got the same problem?

Comment: Provide some code too for getting clear idea

Comment: Provide code and logcat error if exists.

Comment: nothing appeared in LogCat. I used the simple codes that follow Android Volley's example, nothing fancy.
btw, here is it: http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?96cc29c673d35f8f#kHjpH8TyKSbxOo2r8ZCuI7iWpuEd3FbnQYhGva4oO1I=

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and resolved it by declaring the Application class on Manifest.xml (I was missing that...):

```
<application
android:name=".jersey.client.volley.VolleyAPIApplication"
...>
```